# yii2 авторизация(вытянут данные из mysql)

Tags: php, yii2

не могу понять почему после метода `Yii::$app->user->login()` не выполняется вход. Код стандартный (yii base) почти не менял, скину только то, что дополнил:

User.php

```
//    private static $users = [
//        '100' => [
//            'id' => '100',
//            'username' => 'admin',
//            'password' => 'admin',
//            'authKey' => 'test100key',
//            'accessToken' => '100-token',
//        ],
//        '101' => [
//            'id' => '101',
//            'username' => 'demo',
//            'password' => 'demo',
//            'authKey' => 'test101key',
//            'accessToken' => '101-token',
//        ],
//    ];

    private static $users;
    public static function getUsers()
    {
        $users = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT * FROM users")->queryAll();
    }
```

LoginForm.php

```
   public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            User::getUsers();
            $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
        }
        //var_dump($this->_user);
        return $this->_user
    }
```

Вывожу id текущего user, но он остается неизменным (null)

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $test = Yii::$app->user->id;
        $test2 = 'asd';
        return $this->render('index',['t' => $test, 't2' => $test2]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переделайте класс User под ActiveRecord.

```
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%user}}';
    }

    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        return static::findOne(['username' => $username]);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: А для чего? С каких пор Active Record  стал обязательным? Почему я просто не могу создать класс и написать к нему набор методов. Через автоматически сгенерированный модель все работает. Но меня интересует вопрос почему так как указанно в вопросе не работает.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц да вовсе не обязательно. Просто зачем изобретать велосипед. А вообще у вас в классе User видимо должно быть `self::$users = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT * FROM users")->queryAll();`

Answer (score 0):

У вас в функции getuser() не завершено после return $this->, не дописано свойство или метод

Comment: Опечатка при создании вопроса, прошу прощение, исправил. Ошибка актуальна. Все работает через модели отлично, но хотелось бы понять почему так не хочет. Боюсь дело в том что мои познания именно в ООП php не дают этого понять...не дают понять почему возвращается пустой результат. Прошу помощи!